# same img size across browsers

Tags: html, css

Do you guys know how to show same image size across browsers. Or similar size. I'm working on a site and the image i included in a div shows too different in size, especially for Safari, it looks too tiny. The image occupies 90% of the page in most browsers but in Safari it uses about 25% of it.
CSS goes like this

```
 #menu img{

 max-width:70% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;

}
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  img { max-width: 80%; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  img { max-height: 50%; }
}
```

Comment: You're setting `max-width`, leaving the browser free to do what it likes to any size smaller. Can't you just set `width`?

Comment: define fixed width and height in it's container..

Comment: If you set only `max-width` to your `img`, `div` or whatever in html. You set only **maximum** width which this elements can used. Set `min-width` or `width`. and everything will be ok.